# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is now December 2013, which means you get your first ever Community Promotion Ads reset!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting journey logs and journal blogs
- helpful travel guidebooks and research resources
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1582).

Comment: Would it be allowed to use this to promote another proposed site from Area 51? In this case I would promote the **[Expatriates](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates)** proposal.

Comment: @hippietrail You could do it. Ultimately it's up to the community to approve your ad, not me. ♪

Comment: Thanks Grace. Anyone able to make an image? I only had the idea `\-:`

Comment: @hippietrail I've asked a question how to do that (http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/could-we-promote-expatriates-proposal-on-the-site?lq=1) and the banner is here

Answer (score 29):

[image: the free travel guide that anyone can edit]

Comment: A great initiative. Worth to be supported.

Comment: I contribute all my tips to Wikivoyage, and I encourage everyone here to do the same :-) Writing a guide about your city is the best way to rediscover it. The logo has changed so it would be great if the ad could be updated, though. Thanks a lot for the idea Gilles! I also think both sites could benefit a lot from improved collaboration, for instance destination tagging, or directing Wikivoyage:Tourist_Office‎ questions to here.

Comment: @nic I'm not to credit for this, I just copied it from last year's thread. If the logo has changed, feel free to update this answer (just make sure to respect the size constraint).

Answer (score 15):

[image: Expats.SE]

Comment: downvoters care to comment why?

Comment: (because, remember, this is meta, where we discuss travel.se, and this proposal was started by one of our own users - sklivvz, and it'd be nice to give him support for what would be a great sister site to travel.se)

Comment: Everybody would be better of if expat questions were allowed on this site. And in the meanwhile we could support useful initiatives as e.g. wikitravel

Comment: wikivoyage that is ...

Comment: Expatriates is now in public beta... How to change the banner?

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Just hit edit and replace it! Only trouble is finding a good image to replace it with...

Comment: Banner updated after a user on expats produced this (jmac)

Answer (score 10):

[image: Current Travel.SE bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/travel.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: The image size isn't right, this ad won't be shown. I don't know who maintains that app, whoever knows should make a bug report.

Comment: @Gilles don't worry it works (I don't know how and why, but it works) see the screenshot in the chatroom

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe the image size depends on the referer (like the content must, since the URL doesn't depend on the site name). Weird.

Comment: @Dirty-flow I wonder how you got this ad to work. When I try to do it on another site, I get an error that says that I can't use an image from a site other than i.stack.imgur.com.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi try to creat a hyperlink with a random imgur image and then edit the post and add the bounty-list-link

Answer (score 9):

[image: The Guide to Hitchhiking the World!]

Comment: Hitchwiki is the best source of information for hitchhikers. It's a very open community. Happy to see there's an "ad" for it here on this community!

Comment: The size is wrong, I seems to work, but it gets stretched...

Answer (score 7):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 2):

[image: Japanese culture Area51 proposal]