# Could we promote Expatriates proposal on the site?

Tags: support, expat-questions

The Expatriates proposal needs only 30 more commiters to go to beta phase. Because this site is strongly connected with Travel, could we promote it on the Travel site? We have already banner:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/38732

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Community ads](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/community-promotion-ads-2014) would be the place for this.

Feel free to post the banner and the community will vote on it. I'm sure 6 upvotes won't be a problem.

**Edit**: Use this image (URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RHIM.png):

Additionally, it seems [Area51 proposals are already advertised on SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208988/area51-proposals-are-being-advertised-now-all-over-the-network).

[image]

Comment: Good idea, but I don't know how to put that banner in the post so that it displays as picture and not as link :(

Comment: @ŁukaszL.: See update ;)

Comment: but the progress won't update as the commitment would change... anyway great thanx

Comment: @ŁukaszL.: nothing to do about that, sorry :( The community ads only accept images (AFAIK), and this is currently the only way Travel-SE users and mods can promote content.

Comment: OK I thought there's some mechanism for promoting Area51 proposals directly

Comment: We could perhaps do a different image every few percent.... ;)