# Community adverts for questions?

Tags: discussion

Just a thought I was having.  We currently have only a couple of [community adverts](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/community-promotion-ads-2014) - (feel free to add some more), but what about the possibility of:

1. making adverts for our most popular/crazy/fun questions - these can be voted on, obviously
2. making adverts for unanswered questions - say, run an advert for the oldest unanswered question.

Just a late 2.20am thought....input welcomed.

Comment: How do you forsee this working differently to attaching a bounty to them?

Comment: @Gagravarr a bounty only works if you view the featured list. This appears as a picture advert on the right (you may have seen the Wikivoyage ones we have)